# Java Applet using jacob to load com dll method getting Errormessage : NoClassDefFoundError: com/jacob/activeX/ActiveXComponent

Tags: eclipse, dll, applet, jacob

I need to create an Applet that can load a com method, for this purpose I used the java com bridge (jacob) deal with the com dll, and My Environment is set as follow:

- os:win7x64
- IDE:Eclipse32bit-version
- COM DLL:BPIKeyCOM.dll 32-bit version
- com bridge : jacob1.17-32bit version
- server: Tomcatv7.0

I put jacob.dll under C:\Windows\System32 and jacob.jar under WEB-INF\lib

When I run the project, it's working fine in Eclipse. But when deployed on the web, the following error messages appear:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jacob/activeX/ActiveXComponent
at Fmain.Ikeycheck(Fmain.java:180)
at Fmain.init(Fmain.java:73)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:219)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)...
```

It looks like this message is talking about that it can't find `com/jacob/activeX/ActiveXComponent.class`, but I don't understand how.

I've already searched for many solutions and tried to solve it, but it still keeps showing this error message, I use to do sigh jar, make sure the classpath is correct, and even try to change the policy file...etc. But still, it's not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed the dll and jacob.jar into your Java Web container; unfortunately, that is not the user's web browser (e.g. Applet Container). You need to add the dll and jacob.jar file into the applet jar. You should probably also read [this](http://www.einfobuzz.com/2010/04/how-to-create-a-signed-applet.html). It's also important to point out that if your users install a 64-bit jdk, or aren't running Windows - then your Applet will not work.

Comment: when I sign the jar file and do exactly the same as the link you gave me, [link](http://www.einfobuzz.com/2010/04/how-to-create-a-signed-applet.html)
but it always shows me to specify my alias name, and I can't find my keystore in physical location, what can I do ?

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) from Oracle. You'll have to create your keystore for one...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example provided with [jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/files/jacob-project/):

e.g.
jacob-1.17_src.zip\jacob-1.17\samples\com\jacob\samples\applet

This is a nice example how it works - it even has a readme.txt with a full description inside...